# Uploading CSV File in Here API Batch Geocode using Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, here-api

I am having issue in my format in reading csv using python it returns a delimiter issue. How will I read the csv data and set it as data in Here API?

I've tried using StringIO but still same error is returned.

```
import csv
import io
import csv
output = io.StringIO()

with open('Book1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:

        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(row)


headers = {
    'Content-Type': '*',
}

params = (
    ('gen', '8'),
    ('app_id', '123456'),
    ('app_code', '123456'),
    ('action', 'run'),
    ('mailto', ''),
    ('header', 'true'),
    ('indelim', '|'),
    ('outdelim', '|'),
    ('outcols', 'displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country'),
    ('outputCombined', 'false'),
)


data = output.getvalue()


print('https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs' + data)

response = requests.post('https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs',
                         headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

print(response.content)
```

This is the error message being returned .

b'Invalid input header(s) detected: [recid,searchtext,country]. Please fix the input or check the input delimiter setting.'

This is a sample dataframe

recId|searchText|country
0001|Invalidenstraße 116 10115 Berlin|DEU
0002|Am Kronberger Hang 8 65824 Schwalbach|DEU
0003|425 W Randolph St Chicago IL 60606|USA
0004|One Main Street Cambridge MA 02142|USA
0005|200 S Mathilda Ave Sunnyvale CA 94086|USA

Comment: can u share the dataframe?

Comment: I have found the issue it is in the delimiter setting . The dataframe is same as what is posted in their website . I've just edited the | delimeter in the parameter . It was bugging me for the whole day Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue it is in the delimiter setting . The dataframe is same as what is posted in their website . I've just edited the | delimeter in the parameter . It was bugging me for the whole day Thank you